# Multiple Liner Regression with auto-correlation in dependent variable

Tags: regression, arima

I am modeling process data from a chemical plant. I have noticed that for my dependent variable there is significant autocorrelation over time. The values close in time are correlated. What should I do to get the most valid multiple linear regression where I regress with other non-time independent variables. Can I fit an ARIMA model to take out the autocorrelation and then use that as my dependent variable?